# How to pass a variable at build time to custom command or target?

Tags: cmake

**Situation:**

I use a cli-tool that generates a custom firmware update file from an ihex file. This tool takes the version number as input. I'd like to setup a custom command or custom target in my CMakeLists.txt that generates the firmware based on the current version number. This number might change after initially configuring the project.

**Question:**
Is there a way to pass variables or file contents at build time to the command/target?
I was able to parse the version information at build time (using a custom command that runs cmake -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}) but I'm unable to feed it to the command/target, as all the variables of the command/target are set at configuration time. Even trying to use `$ENV` as an indirection did not work.

**CMakeList.txt**

```
# sets ${VERSION} and $ENV{VERSION} at build time
include(cmake/version-file-parsing.cmake)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf parse_version)

add_custom_target(
    generate
    COMMAND ${CUSTOM_TOOL} -i ${HEX_FILE} -v $ENV{VERSION}
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf
)
```

The version variable seems to be empty when using the `generate` target, so it seems it is taken as-is at configuration time and any changes during build time are ignored.

**Update:**

The `version-file-parsing.cmake` works like https://github.com/andrew-hardin/cmake-git-version-tracking does:

```
function(ParseVersion _in_version_file _out_version _out_snapshot)
    ...
endfunction()

function(SetupVersionParsing)
    add_custom_target(parse_version
            ALL
            BYPRODUCTS
            ${VERSION_OUTPUT_FILE_SHORT}
            ${VERSION_OUTPUT_FILE_LONG}
            COMMENT "Parsing version file"
            COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
            -D_BUILD_TIME_VERSION_PARSING=TRUE
            -DVERSION_FILE=${VERSION_FILE}
            -DVERSION_OUTPUT_FILE_SHORT=${VERSION_OUTPUT_FILE_SHORT}
            -DVERSION_OUTPUT_FILE_LONG=${VERSION_OUTPUT_FILE_LONG}
            -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}")
endfunction()

function(Main)
    if (_BUILD_TIME_VERSION_PARSING)
        ParseVersion(${VERSION_FILE} VERSION IS_SNAPSHOT)
        # set env variables or write to file
    else ()
        SetupVersionParsing()
    endif ()
endfunction()

Main()
```